# Audio.js and .ogg on Firefox for Mac

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio, ogg, audiojs

Got a bit of a weird issue. I am using Audio.js to play some audio files.

Across all platforms and all browsers everything works perfectly apart from Firefox for Mac. The files just do not want to play. They download OK and Audio.js outputs thats they have fully downloaded, but will not play. I have tried files uploaded to our cloud storage provider (they stream fine on all the other browsers), the same files served locally and a third party .ogg file found online.

Nothing.

Anyone had issues with .ogg files playing on Firefox for Mac? Would it be a files header issue? Anyone had issues with Audio.js having problems playing .ogg files in FF on a Mac?

Comment: From the docs, ogg vorbis files are not supported. Also, the implementation needs flash in Firefox to work it seems: http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/

Comment: @jsantell Strange thing is that the implementation works perfectly with FF on windows. Only issue is with FF on a mac.

Comment: FF on Windows can use OS-level MP3 implementation, whereas FF on OSX does not have access to the MP3 codec freely.. not sure if that's what's causing it, but it could be used for the feature detection in the library (as it is an OGG)

Comment: @jsantell Want to package that up as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, ogg vorbis files are not supported. Also, the implementation needs flash in Firefox to work it seems: kolber.github.io/audiojs

(Since your test-case works only in FF on Windows, and not FF on OSX):
FF on Windows can use OS-level MP3 implementation, whereas FF on OSX does not have access to the MP3 codec freely.. not sure if that's what's causing it, but it could be used for the feature detection in the library (as it is an OGG)